# Add simple headline like that from \listoftables

Tags: sectioning

How can I add a simple headline, like the one that is added by a command like `\listoftables` or `\listoffigures`?

I wanted to add a text (headline), that is formated like one of these headlines mentioned above.

Comment: Your examples generate more than a heading. Could you explain why something like e.g. `\section` or `\section*` doesn't work for you?

Comment: What i need exaclty is the foramtting of the headline. If i add a section or a chapter, the formatting and position is different to the formatting of the eg. `\listoftables` headline and there is a counting number like "5. My Title"

Comment: Did you try `\section*` or any other sectioning command with an extra `*`? It gives you something formatted like that type of section, but doesn't add or change a section counter and doesn't show up in the table of contents.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i'm looking for. Works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Did you try `\section*` or any other sectioning command with an extra
>   `*`? It gives you something formatted like that type of section, but doesn't add or change a section counter and doesn't show up in the
>   table of contents.

(Merely posting what seems to be the accepted answer as a community wiki.)